# Haskell Average Function using Foldmap

Tags: haskell, arguments, average

I am trying to write a definition "average" in haskell using the code below so that the
function produces the average (mean) of all of the elements in the input
collection. This is what I have so far:

```
> type RunningTotal = (Sum Float, Sum Float)

> getAverage :: RunningTotal -> Float
> getAverage (_, 0) = 0
> getAverage (total, count) = getSum total / getSum count

> average :: Foldable f => f Float -> Float
> average = getAverage . foldMap (\ Sum x -> [Sum x])
```

I get the error:

```
In the pattern: Sum
The lambda expression ‘\ Sum x -> ...’ has two arguments,
but its type ‘Sum t0 -> RunningTotal’ has only one
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(\ Sum x -> [Sum x])’
```

But if I repeat it, with the same argument for both I get:

```
• The constructor ‘Sum’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    • In the pattern: Sum
      In the expression: \ Sum x -> [Sum x]
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘(\ Sum x -> [Sum x], \ Sum x -> [Sum x])’
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please don't change anything but the parenthesis in the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `foldMap` should have the type `Float -> RunningTotal`. The lambda you have given (`\ Sum x -> [Sum x]`) first of all has a syntactic error in it: you probably meant `\(Sum x) -> [Sum x]` (the version you gave is a lambda with two arguments, the first of which is named `Sum`, and the second `x`). This corrected lambda has the type `Sum a -> [Sum a]` which isn't what you want.

The correct lambda is `\x -> (Sum x, Sum 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `\ Sum x -> [Sum x]` now has 2 arguments - `Sum` and `x`. You can fix it as `\(Sum x) -> [Sum x]` or even `( : [])`.